# Frequent PHP script cronjob mixed with sleep()

Tags: php, json, cron, sleep

I want to run a script every 10 seconds or so. I'm not sure about the best way to do this. The reason is I'm using a rest api and I have have to throttle the request a little but I have a lot of requests to make.

Is it a bad practice to run a php file every minute with sleep throttling the requests so one request is made every 10s for a total of 50s?

Also what are some better alternatives for this sort of application (a lot of requests, almost none stop, every 10s)? Alternatives don't have to be php, but I need to make a json request and enter the data into a MySQL database...

I've tried a java application and directly connecting to the MySQL server, but I found that it's a little unreliable because:
1. If your computer loses its internet connection your requests don't get handled
2. The MySQL requests take longer cause they're not being handled locally. On average I've seen up to 100% increase in time; 2s up to 4s.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: `If your computer loses its internet connection your requests don't get handled` how exactly do you expect PHP to handle your external requests without an internet connection?

Comment: im talking about a sever side cron job vs a client side call via java

Comment: Why do you need php and an http server for this at all? If you are working on the server side, then the usual way is to implement a small deamon for such stuff. Such deamon does not have a time limit, it is a single process that goes on forever, which makes the solution more simple. After sleeping for 10 secs it starts a process or thread to run a single job. It doesn't really matter what language you use, anything available on the server should be fine.

Comment: im currently limited to shared hosting but ill definitely look at deamon in the future